# Is there any obj-c libs help us to write an App can simulate different network service like "Network Link Conditioner"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am current building an iOS App,use UIWebview to load any pages.
Right now I'd like to simulate different network service when view a page.
I know iOS6 give iOS developer a "developer" setting and the "Network Link Conditioner" option and do this.
But I'd like any one who use my app can do this too,and he dont need to be an iOS developer.
Does apple has such API for us to use "Network Link Conditioner"?
If not,is there any obj-c libs out there for us to do so?

Comment: Very very very unlikely....

Comment: what's your mean "unlikely"?impossible?

Comment: It goes against Apple's principles of sandboxing.  Maybe if you jailbreak you can, but I don't see how it would be allowed otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the approach Google did with iOS Chrome where they've inserted their own layer between the network and the UIWebView.

The challenge will be doing it in such a way that MIH behaves as closely to other iOS apps as possible.

**EDIT**

Came across this http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#bandwidth_throttling while doing some changes to Akamai's Mobitest Agent for WebPageTest

The ASIHTTP library looks like it's been abandoned but it could be somewhere to start

Comment: Looks like this way only works for the main url,js/css/images of the page will not be effected.Thanks any way.

Comment: For the iOS agents I use with WebPageTest I've always ended up using the Network Link Conditioner - I'll see if I've got anything bookmarked on the Chrome iOS implementation

Comment: This is what I've got bookmarked - http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2012/06/28/perception-of-performance/comment-page-1/#comment-1761355 Chromium source tree might be the other place to look